# How to run TOR on boot instead using Vidalia?

Tags: boot, opensuse, tor

I am new to TOR and I really have a hard time understanding how to set it up. What I did so far:

- run Vidalia from my personal account -- after few seconds I am connected
- run Vidalia from root account -- as above + warning about running TOR as root

In both cases quitting or killing Vidalia leaves TOR service running.

But I would like to run TOR automatically, if possible system-wide (there is "tor" user, without home directory though).

But I cannot run the service manually (`systemctl start tor.service`):

- as root -- (it is not advised, see above) `/etc/tor/torrc` does not exist
- as myself -- not enough priviliges

And I need this to be able to run it on boot, I won't run Vidalia on boot after all.

So — how to skip Vidalia and run TOR service the old fashion way, manually as service? (Vidialia could be useful for GUI configuration, but only that).

**openSUSE 13.2, 64-bit.**

Comment: I'm not familar with zypper, but you have to deinstall Vidalia and install tor package and if you want, install privoxy for assist.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh, I installed Vidalia additionaly (it does not contain TOR), and I use privoxy for years, but I would like to go with TOR step by step (first run it on boot, second run it as relay, third configure it with privoxy).